# Hot to fix "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'"?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's the code with error:

```js
    let createArray = function<T>(length: number, value: T): T[] {
        let result: T[] = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (typeof value === 'string') {
                result[i] = value + '_' + i;  // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.
            } else {
                result[i] = value;
            }
            
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    createArray(3, 'x');
```

I have no idea why Typescript can not recognize the Generics `T` as `string` in this case.

How can I fix it?

Comment: `T` could be a specific kind of string, like `createArray<"foo">(3, "foo")`. The string `"foo_0"` wouldn't match that type. Do you want it to be that if `T` extends from `string`, then the function returns a `string[]`, not a `T[]`?

Comment: What happens if you do `createArray(3, typeof 'x')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Overloading](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/function-overloading):

```
function createArray(length: number, value: string): string[];

function createArray<T>(length: number, value: T): T[];

function createArray<T>(length: number, value: T|string): (T|string)[] {
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
            result[i] = value + '_' + i;  // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.
        } else {
            result[i] = value;
        }
        
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(createArray(3, 'x'));           // ["x_0", "x_1", "x_2"] 

console.log(createArray(3, 23));            // [23, 23, 23]

console.log(createArray(3, {hi: "hello"})); // [{
                                            //   "hi": "hello"
                                            // }, {
                                            //   "hi": "hello"
                                            // }, {
                                            //   "hi": "hello"
                                            // }]
```

See [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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).